# Retrieving Value from EditText in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm going through Google's Android Developer page on Dialogs, specifically [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents) section. However, instead of creating the DialogFragment's message programmatically, I made a pre-set layout named `layout_newpayperiod.xml` with the following elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_payperiod"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:entries="@array/pay_periods"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_savepercent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:hint="Percent to Save"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_payment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:hint="Total Payment"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I call the DialogFragment it shows up as normal, with the Spinner having the proper values. I filled in the entries and hit "OK", but when I try to retrieve the values from the Spinner and two EditText fields, the app forces close with a `NumberFormatException: Invalid double ""`. I get the feeling I'm not retrieving the Views properly. Can anyone help me figure this out please? Thanks!

```
public class StartPayperiodDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

/* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
 * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
 * Each method passees the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it.
 */
public interface StartPayperiodDialogListener{
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
StartPayperiodDialogListener listener;

// Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the StartPayperiodDialogListener
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try{
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        listener = (StartPayperiodDialogListener) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement StartPayperiodDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View transactionLayout = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_newpayperiod, null);
    builder.setView(transactionLayout)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Send the positive button event back to the calling activity
            listener.onDialogPositiveClick(StartPayperiodDialogFragment.this);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Send the negative button event back to the calling activity
            listener.onDialogNegativeClick(StartPayperiodDialogFragment.this);
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

In MainActivity.class, the callback method:

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // User pressed OK, so we need to grab the values from the
    // dialog's fields and apply them to the Views in the Main
    // Activity

    View transactionLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_newpayperiod, null);

    // Start with the payment amount
    EditText paymentEt = (EditText) transactionLayout.findViewById(R.id.edittext_payment);
    TextView paymentTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_paycheck);
    paymentTv.setText(moneyFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(paymentEt.getText().toString())));

    // Next, the percent to save
    EditText savingsEt = (EditText) transactionLayout.findViewById(R.id.edittext_savepercent);
    TextView savingsTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_savings);
    savingsTv.setText(savingsEt.getText().toString() + "%");

    // Then, the pay period
    Spinner periodSp = (Spinner) transactionLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner_payperiod);
    TextView periodTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_payperiod);
    periodTv.setText(periodSp.getSelectedItem().toString());

    // Finally, let's update the daily allowance amount and clear
    // the adapter
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    TextView allowanceTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_allowance);
    Double allowanceValue;
    switch(periodSp.getSelectedItemPosition()){
        case(0):    // Daily
            allowanceValue = Double.parseDouble(paymentTv.getText().toString());
            break;
        case(1):    // Weekly
            allowanceValue = Double.parseDouble(paymentTv.getText().toString()) / 7;
            break;
        case(2):    // 2 Weeks
            allowanceValue = Double.parseDouble(paymentTv.getText().toString()) / 14;
            break;
        case(3):    // 30 Days
            allowanceValue = Double.parseDouble(paymentTv.getText().toString()) / 30;
            break;
        default:    // Debugging purposes only
            allowanceValue = 42.0;
            break;
    }
    allowanceTv.setText(Double.toString(allowanceValue));
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    // User pressed OK, so we need to grab the values from the
    // dialog's fields and apply them to the Views in the Main
    // Activity

    // Start with the payment amount
    Dialog dialogView = dialog.getDialog();
    EditText paymentEt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_payment);
```

... etc. (Retrieve any other views from the dialog by querying the dialogView in the same way.)

Your inflate code "inflates" a brand new version of that view. You want to access the one that was created in the dialog.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but I'm getting a NullPointerException on the `EditText paymentEt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_payment);` line. I suspect the dialog.getView() call isn't doing what we expect...

Comment: @Argus9 you are correct. That would be the proper use for a normal fragment, but for a DialogFragment, you need to use getDialog(). I have edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: Also, if you're in other places in the class that extends DialogFragment (after the item has been created, mind you), calling getDialog().findViewById(...) will also give you access to the widgets in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this line `View transactionLayout = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_newpayperiod, null);`  messes everything. Maybe it's not messing, but you're getting address of freshly created layout and assign it to `transactionLayout` reference. Then you're getting Views from that layout `EditText paymentEt = (EditText) transactionLayout.findViewById(R.id.edittext_payment);` which are certainly uninitialisted. It has value empty string value -> "";

I think you should use findViewById to get reference to your EditText's as you do with your TextView's. But as you are in your `MainActivity` which layout is probably not a parent view to your `R.layout.layout_newpayperiod`, you must find a way to do that properly.

You've got your `DialogFragment` as parameter in this `onDialogPositiveClick`callback  method. So you can obtain it's `View` and the layout you're looking for - that contains your EditText's

Sorry for editing this post so many times.

Comment: I think the only reason I chose not to do this is because when using findViewById as I did with the TextViews, I got a NullPointerException. It's as if the elements exist in R.id, but the app can't find them at runtime. I'll try this again and see if it helps.

Comment: Oh, also - the TextViews are present in the MainActivity's layout XML file, which is called in SetContentView() in the Activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: You get Null references because these views are not related to each other. Check out Jay Bobzin's answer that should solve your problem